# 長時間実行するプログラムの標準出力を日別ファイルに保存したい

Tags: linux, ubuntu

タイトルの通りで、日付を跨ぐごとにリダイレクト先が変わるイメージです。

簡単なサーバプログラムを作成したのですが、出力は標準出力に行っており、単にファイルにリダイレクトして一週間などと起動していたらログファイルが取り扱いづらい行数になってしまいます。
真面目にするのならばプログラム自体のロギング機能を充実させるべきかもしれませんが、パイプに渡すだけでこのような処理を行ってくれる標準、または有名なプログラムは既にありますか？

Comment: 日付が条件ではなさそうですが、この記事 [Log rotation of stdout?](https://superuser.com/q/291368) がその話題を扱っていると思われます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cronolog` はどうでしょうか。Debian, Ubuntu なら標準パッケージ。

`foobar |cronolog /var/log/%Y/%m/%d/access.log` のようにして使えます。